# Why does the word 'peasant' have such a negative meaning in English?

Tags: meaning, translation

In French the word **paysan (fem. paysanne)* translates to English as 'farmer', as well as 'peasant'. (Collins).

It is by no means demeaning in many European countries (including France) to refer to someone as a *paysan*. It means a type of country person, but not necessarily one of low social status. Many landowners are described thus.

According to the OED almost all the meanings of *peasant* are demeaning, indeed they take the trouble to point out that it is a word which has effectively ceased to refer anyone in Britain, and is generally applied to agricultural communities in poor countries. *Peasant* is nowadays mostly used in Britain as a term of abuse. Not even agricultural labourers are referred to as 'peasants'.

Was there ever a wealthy peasant class in Britain, and in her original dominions such as America, Australia etc, and if so where has it gone?

Answer (score 9):

That wealthy class would certainly not see themselves as peasants. 
They were the owners of land, and one of the ways to turn land into money was to have people work it. The ones that did that work were the peasants.

There has never been a wealthy peasant class, because a peasant was by definition a person who worked a small piece of land, which often did not belong to him, and he had to pay taxes over the produce. Successful peasant might end up with a bit more land and the ability to hire hands, but they would still belong to the lowest class.

Only after the demise of the feudal system did farming become eventually a real enterprise, where the farmer owns his own land and can run a sizeable farm as a business.

This is not unique to Britain but true for most of (Western) Europe, where the feudal system was in place throughout the Middle Ages.

As for French, although I *have* heard *paysan* used in a pejorative sense, it's not as strong as "peasant"in English. Why that is - maybe because of the quite harsh reset of social values after the French Revolution?

The Dutch "boer", though the normal way to refer to a farmer, certainly also has negative connotations, and when applied to someone who is not a farmer, carries the message that that person is uncivilized, uneducated and rude. It is also commonly attached to other nouns to indicate negativity, although strangely enough it's also used to indicate "old fashioned, artisanal quality".

So it is not just in English the word has negative connotations :)
(And I realized why nobody will ever understand the Dutch or their language :P )

Comment: German "Bauer" (farmer) can also be used in a pejorative sense.

Comment: Yes. The great difference between Britain and France was the system of land inheritance. Entailed estates ensured that landowners remained big in England. And any country person not a landowner was of a far poorer class. In France the estates tended to be divided equally between the offspring of a deceased owner - which meant that average farm sizes were far smaller - disadvantageous from an efficiency standpoint - but more socially equitable. It was this, better-off peasant class which ultimately ensured the success of the Revolution in the late 18th century.

Answer (score 7):

> In French the word *paysan (fem. paysanne) translates to English as 'farmer', as well as 'peasant'. (Collins).

One certainly wouldn't call a gentleman farmer who owned a large estate a *paysan*, whether in French or as that word has been re-borrowed into English.

When *peasant* came into English with the Normans, it denoted a rank, as well as a rural rather than urban life.

Just how derogatory that is depends on your politics—the peasant might be the only person you hold as having value, compared to the greedy bourgeois and the decadent aristocrats!—and your romantic inclinations—the peasant has been the focus of many a pastoral fantasy on the part of the non-peasant classes, from Walter Raleigh's "Shepherd" poems, through Marie Antoinette's silk dairymaid costume through to various back-to-nature movements.

But still, the peasant is certainly "lowly" in both the English and French use, and the rest follows from how one reacts to that lowly station. That the English haven't had a good beheading of the upper classes by the lower classes since 1649, while the French not only picked up the habit a good hundred years later, but also stuck with their republic for longer than the ten years the English managed (albeit with some setbacks along the way) would have some effect.

Comment: +1 Also, we (meaning both Brits and Yanks) have a useful native term for the prosperous agriculturist. *Peasant* refers to the degraded inhabitants of unhappy nations which lack Roast Beef, Brown Ale, and The (not merely A) Bill of Rights; *our* tongue celebrates the *Yeoman*.

Comment: @StoneyB I think we Yanks would more often recognize the Gentleman Farmer.

Comment: @bib I may be showing my age and ethnos. My father was a student of Donald Davidson's, and the Fugitives/Southern Agrarians were fond of *yeoman* for the agricultural class. *Gentleman Farmer* would probably for them have suggested something quite different: the remnant of the old Planter class.

Comment: @bib, They're like Big Agriculture, but not actually anywhere near as big, with a stronger fondness for tweed, and a working definition of "old money" of, "before you were throwing your tea into the sea".

Comment: I think it was **your** tea they were throwing into the sea; but, yeah, Gentleman Farmer to me means the gentry, the squirearchy.

Comment: @oerkelens I am responding both to you and to Jon Hanna, (+1 to both) indeed to everyone who has collectively supplied important information. However no one mentioned perhaps the most important word of all which was 'enclosures'. The other important word is 'land primogeniture'. It was the enclosures movement which got underway in the 16th century and continued until the 19th which ended the feudal system and concentrated land 'ownership'. Ultimately this meant that average farm sizes were much greater in England, and eventually in her dominions than in France and elsewhere. (Continued)

Comment: @StoneyB - there is a difference between yeomen and peasants.  Yeomen are free, peasants are not.

Comment: @WS2 - the end of Enclosures movement took what was traditionally common land away from use by the poor and made it private property, usually of the wealthy in the area so the poor could no longer use it to supplement their lives.

Comment: This allowed for farms to be run as commercial enterprises able to take advantage of mechanisation etc. 'Primogeniture' meant 'entailement' of estates, meaning that the eldest son inherited everything, which prevented farms being broken up on death, and ever sub-divided into smaller and smaller holdings. Hence the character of British farming became much more that of entrepreneurship. In Europe 'peasant' holdings continue to the present day, which explains much of the agricultural disconnect  between Britain and the EU. In France the 'paysan' is honorable, in Britain they are obsolete.

Comment: @Oldcat  At times when the distinction was of legal force, *peasant* was rarely used in English in that sense; the preferred term was *villein* -- which is another part of the reason that, as OP observes, *peasant* tends to be used of non-British agriculturist.

Comment: @StoneyB Under enclosures the *villeins* eventually disappear. And mechanisation meant fewer hands needed, which also explains why Britain had an industrial revolution - hordes of spare labour for the 'dark satanic mills', augmented by Irish arriving at the time of the famine. French rural society is quite different, beautifully documented by Emile Zola in *La Terre*, but if you contrast the scene with that of a British writer, such as Thomas Hardy, it encapsulates the difference between the two systems. So much of the character of the modern Anglo world dates from enclosures.

Comment: @StoneyB Re your Roast Beef, Brown Ale etc. Be careful, you are speaking to an Irishman. They have their own views about wealthy British landowners.

Comment: @bib The first 'Gentlemen farmers' were the inheritors of the entailed estates. It was the concentration of wealth in this way which created the first capitalists. If you follow Downton Abbey, the Granthams are quintessentially the class I'm talking about. But they didn't have a son, and the only heir has been killed leaving a baby son. It was well into the 20th C before entailment disappeared.

Comment: @WS2 1) I think you need to add a third critical term: *commutation*.  2) I trust Jon Hanna recognizes that my rhetoric is bucally articulated.

Comment: @StoneyB 1.Yes, by that I assume you mean the conversion of the  Church lands after the reformation. 2. 'Bucally' with a single c is a new one on me, as well as on Oxford Dictionaries. Double cc, and it's to do with the mouth?

Comment: @WS2 1)More generally, commutation of feudal service into cash rent, which went on continually from the High Middle Ages down to 1840 or so. 2) Sorry, typo: *buccally*, specifically of the *cheek*

Comment: @WS2 we Irish appreciate beef too, and may well argue in favour of the quality of ours, though I prefer mine cooked after the manner of the French. On the topic of ale, I would have to give the British the prize there until very recently (thankfully there has been a recent ale renaissance here) and the British do still have the better pubs on average, at least as far as what they serve goes. But then, I do consider myself British too, as politically complicated as that might be.

Comment: @JonHanna And I'm sitting here wearing a London Irish rugby jersey (they play at the Reading Football Ground). And the sponsors name emblazoned on it? Who else? GUINNESS. You say we have the better pubs, but they do stay open a bit longer in the Republic, you'll have to admit!

Comment: @Oldcat, strictly, yeomen are free, peasants *may* not be  a yeoman is though owns land, at least for some of the period in which the term has been in use, as the definition has changed over the centuries, even for a while being an American term for someone who owned land but not slaves, and mostly worked it themselves.

Comment: @WS2 I'm too much a gourmand to rate Guinness highly as a stout (originally a drink invented in London), regardless of whether one of the leading financial dynasties of the British Empire stands as particularly Irish or not (I may feel partly British, but that parts a bigger republican than the Irish part). Of course, we both suffer from short drinking hours as the result of said empire thinking it would winning the war against the Kaiser faster if late night drinking water temporarily prohibited, with almost everywhere else taking a much more relaxed approach.

Comment: "it would winning the war"? I've got to stop posting here from my phone.

Comment: @JonHanna As we are a language site, I think I should point out that you are probably a 'gourmet' rather than a 'gourmand'. The latter is a ravenous non-discerning eater (and drinker) who shovels it in; perhaps the sort of person who would down a few pints of Guinness. Last time I was in Ireland (about 12 years ago), touring the west coast, I was amazed at the number of Michelin starred restaurants. The impression I got was that the tourism part of the government were doing their best to make the country a venue for up-market fishing, shooting and golfing holidays.

Comment: @WS2 I'm blaming my phone for that too ;) If anything, the west coast has too few Michelin star restaurants; that Gregan's Castle didn't get one during Viljanen's time as head chef brought any annual response from several Irish chefs of "don't care if I don't get one now, they clearly ignore Ireland outside of Dublin if Viljanen doesn’t have have one" though I can only report second hand as while I never made it there during that period. If Michelin is your standard of dining, next time do the east coast and stay in the Cliff House in Waterford.

Comment: @JonHanna Michelin is certainly not our usual standard. But I seem to recall that we were booked into a hotel in Killarney, which much to our surprise had some very high rating. It may not have been Michelin. Perhaps my memory is playing tricks. But the standard of restaurants was very much higher than UK tourist places, for the reason, I supposed, that they were attracting an up-market clientele from the USA and Europe. (Very few British - I think this was before the Good Friday agreement)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13051/discussion-between-jon-hanna-and-ws2)

Answer (score 2):

*"**peasant**"* may come from old French word "*païsan*", you do **not** translate it to *"paysan"*.

The word that better corresponding to the meaning of *"peasant"* is *"serf"* :

- do not own the land or a very little part
- have hard work
- be exploited by the owner of the land or a powerful economic entity

While *"**farmer**"* matches with the meaning of *"paysan"* used in French.

---

In French, call someone who is not from big cities and came to work there "Paysan", and you will see if it has no negative connotation. (See [Amphiteóth comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152074/why-does-the-word-peasant-have-such-a-negative-meaning-in-english#comment-559506))

Comment: My *Concise Oxford HACHETTE French Dictionary* does not have an entry for païsan, and I had never come across it before. I have to admit that *pays* and *paysan* always seem idiosyncratic as the *y* is rarely found in French.

Comment: @WS2 This [book](https://books.google.de/books?id=gIRrrAj7kE0C&pg=PT160&lpg=PT160&dq=pa%C3%AFs+ancien+fran%C3%A7ais&source=bl&ots=p13ozfLfnQ&sig=pSNYEs8nqmqexasWCNMHIXGTFf8&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=kfqQVZzkI4L8ygOawZzoDw&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=pa%C3%AFs%20ancien%20fran%C3%A7ais&f=false) and [this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/de/definition/learner/peasant) (word origin section) may help. What your dictionary tells about peasant etymology? (BTW a concise dictionary is not perfect for high level research)

Comment: Oh, I am well aware of that. I am not a French scholar by any means. But it is quite a good dictionary and I was surprised not to find it. But your links are interesting.

Comment: @WS2 I used [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peasant) also but people don't like it there, I find it very nice for etymology, even if meaning is not always correctly explained.

Comment: @Amphiteóth The negative connotation is coming from the state of being a *"serf"* → having no education → be stupid...  thank for the link and support

Comment: See this French [dictionary](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/paysan); 1718 for the _paysan_ spelling (_païsan_ before). Negative connotation is very early, by 13th: «nigaud, imbécile; rustre» etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

@Nancy: Interesting, but the correct way to write that Italian word is "paesani", and it doesn't have negative connotations generally.
The Italian word for "peasants" is probably "villani", which does have negative connotations.

(I'm Italian and Italian is my mother tongue; I know I'm not answering the original question--if not indirectly--but I wanted to correct a spelling mistake so I hope this message isn't inappropriate).

Comment: When you get more points you will be able to use "comments", instead of using an "answer" for a comment such as this.

Answer (score 1):

My decades-old copy of the Oxford English Dictionary says "peasant" came into English as a word for *foreigners* of low class. I am not sure this has changed much.

So there never really were any British, let alone American, "peasants." One who worked the land but was not a serf might be a "villein" (talk about acquiring negative connotations!).

BTW: In my old New York neighborhood that had a lot of Italian immigrants, my hairdresser had some customers who were "paisani." They came from the same village or same small part of Italy, I gathered, and always brought food or other gifts in return, I think, for a free or heavily discounted haircut. Callie was always glad to see a paisano.

Comment: However, 'foreign' in the days of peasants, didn't necessarily mean from a different country. It could refer to someone from a different *village*.

Answer (score 1):

In days of old, the word peasant was used to show status of say, being under a king, or other so-called authority. The royals needed subjects. Those subjects were usually the lower class people who did not have the financial means to say otherwise. In the broad sense this was not bad, because in the long run, money does not equate to happiness. The world today is obsessed with stocks, bonds, and bank accounts. Which, in the big scheme of things mean nothing.

There is nothing wrong with being a peasant, in fact, I think it is better than having wealth. Being poor is better than being rich. It should not be considered demeaning. The world today is PC, or afraid of offending someone else. In reality, before the term PC came about, people of lesser means were better off than those of status. It was, and is, very hard work. Genesis 3:19 says - "By the sweat of your brow you will eat your bread, until you return to the ground" — There was nothing wrong with being a peasant in that sense.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: *There is nothing wrong with being a peasant, in fact, I think it is better than having wealth.* Well, there's an opinion that is seldom aired. :)

Comment: I accept the sincerity with which you have provided this answer and for that alone I give you an upvote - but it really doesn't answer the question, does it?

Answer (score 1):

What about in Spanish?

Google translate gives three translations of peasant. Seems like the first one is neutral; the other two seem to have negative connotations.
el campesino
peasant, countryman, country person

el palurdo
hick, boor, yokel, peasant, rube, bumpkin

el paleto
hick, bumpkin, peasant, hayseed, gawky

And then there is this Cuban slang term: Guajiro/guajira
A slang word for “peasant,” usually used to describe those who live and work the land in the west of the country. Your guide will likely talk about “los guajiros” if you take a trip to the Viñales valley.
https://theculturetrip.com/caribbean/cuba/articles/the-8-cuban-slang-terms-you-need-to-know/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/414683)

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. All it lacks is the observation that *peasant* has multple meanings, and that translations into other languages help illustrate that.